# Anonymize files,with a array of specified words, Python

Tags: python-3.x

So i'm writting an anonymizer and I'm having trouble with figuring out, how  to replace a Name in a textfile. I have an array with names that should get anonymized, refered here as `text` here's my code, it should go into an other file and check if the words match, and if `true`, it should get replaced. As programming is still a foreign language to me, I would love to read a comprehensive answer

```
for words in fin_message:
    if words == text : 
        new_list = words.replace(text, "xxx") 
        print(new_list) 
    else:
        print(words)
```

Comment: What is `fin_message`?

Comment: @L3viathan it's the file in which it should be replaced

Comment: `fin_message` is a _file_, as returned by `open`? Or is it the contents of a file?

Comment: returned by `open()` but then split up by `split()`

Answer (score 1):

Since `text` is a list, you can't directly compare it to "word", but you *can* test whether the word is *in* `text`:

```
...
if words in text: 
    print("xxx")
...
```

This will, however, print the words in the text file one by one. If instead, you want to print the text file as-is, except for the replacements, you could iterate over the lines of the file, and inside the lines over the banned names. Something like this:

```
banned_words = ["Peter", "Paul", "Mary"]

with open("my_file.txt") as f:
    for line in f:
        for forbidden in banned_words:
            line.replace(forbidden, "xxx")
        print(line)
```